# ProgressBar looper exception with runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, network-programming

As I coded some kind of HTML-downloader for Android, I decided to make use of  ProgressBar but it threw `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!`. I know this exception is thrown when a function requires to be called on main thread, but I called it inside `runOnUiThread()` Please look at the code below.

```
//Inside a worker thread's run()
progressbar.setInterminate(true); //No Exception here
//Connect and get InputStream.
progressbar.setMax(conn.getContentLength()); //No exception here, too
progressbar.setProgress(0); //No exception here.
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressbar.setInterminate(false); //Exception here!
    }
});
```

I have tried moving `setProgress()` below `setInterminate(false)` but that did nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume your worker thread runs only once to download something? Is that right?

Comment: @Inferno You're correct. Maybe I should use a shared value to archive that?

Comment: And what is `progress`? Where is it coming from? You seem to have two different progressbar objects: `progressbar` and `progress`. Please provide more details and maybe add the stacktrace.

Comment: @inferno That was a typo caused when editing the code to remove HTTP-related codes. And backtrace... I'll try to add them when possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to programming, and I know nothing about HTML-downloaders and such, but I'll try to help. From what I've read, the default main thread is where everything is run, unless a new Thread is created. So what would happen if you had `progress.setInterminate(false);` up beside `progressbar.setProgress(0);` instead of in a new Thread??

Comment: Well, as code says, `//Inside a worker thread's run()`, the code above *is* in a new thread. And function `runOnUiThread(Runnable r)` runs r *in the main thread*. Besides, I had to use a new thread here because Android won't let people access network from main thread. (Due to blocking problem)

Comment: Well, sorry I couldn't be of any help. No one had answered, so I gave it a shot. Good luck with your issue! If you want me to delete my answer due to it being useless, simply say so.